# Title is not showing up in ion-view field in ionic 1.0.0-beta.12

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ionic-framework

I was trying to use `ion-view` in latest version of ionic framework but `title` is not showing up .
May be I am doing anything wrong.

Here is my Codepen :

http://codepen.io/vinay885/pen/ZYOPVa

But with older version , it is showing up : - http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/AHIuh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change your `nav-bar` tag to `ion-nav-bar`.